# Git Issue : Unable to merge Dev branch to master

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to merge dev branch to master.
I am getting below message.

I did

```
git checkout 84c65de
```

followed by

```
git merge remotes/origin/master
```

I resolved issues in Vs Code.
What to do next.
Shall I push change to dev/master?

[image]

Comment: git pull origin dev --rebase
Resolve conflicts 
and push changes to dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the changes are resolved you need to add and commit them. Then the merge will be complete and you can push your code

Comment: Push it to Detached Head / dev branch or master branch?

Comment: It seems that you have merged master into dev no?

Comment: To merge dev into master you need to checkout the master branch and then do git merge dev

Comment: git checkout master >> git merge remote/origin/dev >> resolves issues >> commit into master >> Push to master branch
Is it right?

Comment: that is correct